# How to count found strings in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When you search for a string in Visual Studio Code with Ctrl-F it doesn't display number of occurrences.

Is it possible to find out somehow?

On the other hand it displays a number of hits next to a filename when you search all files with Ctrl-Shift-F.

Comment: Did you find a way, sometimes I just want a quick count, I don't want to grep or do a proper search.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once you have the search bar pulled up with Ctrl-F, click the triangle on the left side of the search bar. The occurrence count of your search term will be displayed.

Happy coding!

Comment: I don't see any triangle in search-bar. See here, I was looking for "Date" http://imgur.com/PmpLxuK

Comment: Ah, interesting! Here's a screenshot of it running on my Windows machine: http://imgur.com/fM2WOWA. It looks the same on my Mac. I'm now wondering if you have an older version of VS Code. Check for updates in VS Code and see if that fixes things. Otherwise, let me know. It might be a bug specific to your OS. I can open an issue on the GitHub page. (Side note: The thing I mentioned about the triangle to expand the search view I think applied to an older version of VS Code. I was going from memory...)

Comment: Seems you were right. I'm running Linux and it seems they're running late with releasing Linux updates. I was running December 2015 version, and I can swear I looked for an update a couple of weeks ago. Anyway now I have 10.8, although the latest is 10.9 for Win/Mac. And it does display occurrence count :) . Thanks!

Comment: This maxes out at 999

Comment: Shows only 19999+ as count but I need the exact count. (Debian8 VSCode 1.19.1)

Comment: I look for equivalent of this: `grep -o 'your awesome search text' foobar.xml | wc -l`

Comment: This does not show actual count - it shows 19999+ for higher numbers...

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem as [csonuryilmaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1750142/csonuryilmaz) mentioned in the comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35532438/10675644), I needed the exact count of the string, even if it is 19999+. I ended up opening the file in **Notepad++**, there you can count all occurences when searching for a string.

Maybe not the best solution if you want/have to use only Visual Studio Code, but for my problem this was a good enough workaround.

Comment: For Mac users, as far as I know Notepad++ doesn't have an app for Mac, instead you can use Sublime Text for this.

Comment: For Linux users, Gedit works for 32k occurrences.

Comment: For Mac Users, Open in textEdit. simplest way to view such files. Working fine with 50 MB file. Maybe cause issues with large files like 500 MB

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can count string occurrences with the command FIND /C "string you're searching" filename.txt

So on VSCode, you can open the console (ctrl + ') and type the command. It's one workaround to count string on large files without have to install any new extensions.

Answer (score 0):

click the down faced triangle and then choose 'find all'

[image]

and then the matched string number should be visible on the bottom left:
[image]

Comment: The question is about Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @Mark This is a visual studio interface/IDE.

Comment: Yes , but the question is about Visual Studio Code - a different product.  Similar in this regard, but slightly different and answered above.